# How to create a random sample from a vector of elements?

Tags: rust, sample

I used this code to create a random sample for the numbers 0 to 49. Now I want to create a random sample for a custom set of values. For example: select a sample of 5 from `[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 22, 32, 45]`. How can I do this?

```
use rand::{seq, thread_rng}; // 0.7.3

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let sample = seq::index::sample(&mut rng, 50, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you can use a permutation from the [permutate](https://docs.rs/permutate/0.3.2/permutate/) crate:

```
extern crate permutate; // 0.3.2

use permutate::Permutator;
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut stdout = stdout.lock();
    let list: &[&str] = &["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    let list = [list];
    let mut permutator = Permutator::new(&list[..]);

    if let Some(mut permutation) = permutator.next() {
        for element in &permutation {
            let _ = stdout.write(element.as_bytes());
        }
        let _ = stdout.write(b"\n");
        while permutator.next_with_buffer(&mut permutation) {
            for element in &permutation {
                let _ = stdout.write(element.as_bytes());
            }
            let _ = stdout.write(b"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`IteratorRandom`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html) to get a much shorter solution. This is an extension trait for iterators, it offers convenience functions such as [`choose_multiple`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html#method.choose_multiple) and [`choose_multiple_fill`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html#method.choose_multiple_fill):

```
use rand::{seq::IteratorRandom, thread_rng}; // 0.6.1

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let sample = v.iter().choose_multiple(&mut rng, 2);

    println!("{:?}", sample);
}
```

Comment: The word `choose_multiple` is a bit confusing. Does this sample with or without replacement? "multiple" suggests it is sampling with replacement, but the docs don't mention anything about it. Just a case of lack of overloading (semantically it is the same as `choose`?) forces to use a function name that can be interpreted wrongly?

Comment: AFAIK, `choose_multiple` doesn't sample with replacement.

Comment: The name in isolation is a confusing, but it's defined in `IteratorRandom` so I think `choose_multiple` and `choose_multiple_fill` unambiguously choose without replacement. An iterator doesn't iterate with replacement, so I'd imagine that derived functions do not use replacement either.

But I agree that this should be documented none the less!