# Function to sample N elements from array

Tags: random, rust, std

Suppose we have an array:

```
let arr: [u8; 10] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Is there a function in Rust to choose `N` random elements from it without repetitions? Equivalent to python's `random.sample` function.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning is that Rust doesn't provide random-related functionality in its standard library, so you need to use an external crate (library). The most commonly used one is [`rand`](https://crates.io/crates/rand). The answers given so far are based on that crate.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create a random sample from a vector of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829511/how-to-create-a-random-sample-from-a-vector-of-elements)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`choose_multiple`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose_multiple):

```
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let arr: [u8; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let sample: Vec<_> = arr.choose_multiple (&mut rng, 3).collect();
    println!("{:?}", sample);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84e3b88d0485828520ba58b8fd546c9f)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sample`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html#) for getting a sample over indexes, then just iterate and get those from the original array:

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use rand::seq::index::sample;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let arr: [u8; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let sample: Vec<u8> = sample(&mut rng, arr.len(), 3)
        .iter()
        .map(|i| arr[i])
        .collect();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=494d4533124c8d06c5214fcab43772e1)